# Is there any way to run actionscript 1 code in a flash project running under 3?

Tags: flash, actionscript

I've got some legacy code that I really don't have time to rewrite. Is there any way to mark a code block so that flash player reads it as actionscript 1?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actionscript 1/2 and Actionscript 3 run under different VMs, therefore it's impossible to run AS1 in an AS3 project.